# Implementing FullCalendar date range selection

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fullcalendar

Is there a way to implement `FullCalendar` date range selection in a way that user can click on one day and that becomes the start of the range and on another day that becomes the end of the range?

In documentation I can only see there is this possibility to click and drag in order to select days and the same thing for mobile where `longPressDelay` can be altered, but it would be more convenient to have users select the range by clicking or tapping on dates instead of holding and dragging to create a date range.

I tried setting selectMirror to false and selectable to true, but that didn't change anything. This is my calendar component:

```
const BookingCalendar = ({ onSelectRange }: BookingCalendarProps) => {
  const calendarRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
  const [calendarHeight, setCalendarHeight] = useState(0)
  const [reservedDates, setReservedDates] = useState<Date[]>([])

  const handleSelect = ({ start, end }: DateSelectArg) => {
    onSelectRange(start, end)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    // Mocked reserve dates - TODO: get dates from API
    const dates = [
      new Date('2023-05-01'),
      new Date('2023-05-05'),
      new Date('2023-05-10'),
      new Date('2023-05-18')
    ]
    setReservedDates(dates)

    if (calendarRef.current) {
      const height = calendarRef.current.offsetHeight
      setCalendarHeight(height)
    }
  }, [calendarRef])

  const today = new Date()
  const oneYearFromNow = new Date(today.getFullYear() + 1, today.getMonth(), today.getDate())

  return (
    <div className="h-screen max-h-[350px] sm:max-h-[600px]" ref={calendarRef}>
      <FullCalendar
      plugins={[dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
      initialView="dayGridMonth"
      selectable={true}
      selectMirror={false}
      dayMaxEvents={1}
      select={handleSelect}
      height={calendarHeight}
      events={reservedDates.map((date) => ({ start: date, allDay: true, backgroundColor: 'red', overlap: false, editable: false }))}
      eventDisplay="background"
      selectOverlap={false}
      longPressDelay={1}
      validRange={{
        start: today,
        end: oneYearFromNow
      }}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Since, from fullCalendar's perspective, you would be selecting two non-contiguous dates, it won't support that natively at all. You'll have to write your own code to maintain the state of the two selections, and then call the select() function with the dates selected, to cause an actual selection within fullCalendar itself.